# Is there any working method to mount Ext4 partitions on 64 bit Android 5?

Tags: file-system, mount, ext4

Is seems that, as for today, there are no working methods (apps or hacks) to make **Ext4** partitions work (read/write) on my **Android v5.1 64 bits**.
My device is a *Jiayu S3* with a Xtreme ROM (not stock, but still Jiayu official MOD) based on v5.1.0.

This is what has been **tested** until now:

- [[root] Ntfs Mounter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kwull.ntfsmounter&hl=en) (Application failure on boot)
- [[USB OTG Helper]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg) (No card detected)
- [[Root]StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) (No card detected)

Having no more data, I must assume that the problem could come from some incompatibility with the 64 bit version of the operating system.

Does anyone know of a method to make **Ext4** partitioned SD cards be mount on **64 bit Android v5** devices?

Comment: Wow, I literally just asked the same question. Seeing as yours hasn't been answered in over a year, I guess I'll go back to fat32

Comment: I am on Android 7.0 and don't want to use exFat partition instead I want to create multiple ext4 partitions including one for app to SD.any luck doing this on higher versions of Android and I should be able to write to those ext4 as well

Comment: @answerseeker : maybe you could help by linking to your question here, or mark this one as possible duplicate.